# Serialization throws exception

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

What i'm doing is to serialize class through background task and it throws exception

> *Cannot serialize member 'BackgroundTask.BackgroundTaskDescription.Emails' of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IList*.

My class structure is shown below.

```
public sealed class BackgroundTaskDescription
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string dueTime { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Emails { get; set; }
}
```

How i implement this.? I need List for storing emails through background task.

Answer (score 3):

`XmlSerializer` does not handle properties of type `IList<T>`. There are some workarounds, the most straightforward of which is to change the type of the property to `List<T>.`

Add appropriate `[Serializable]` and Xml attributes to your class.

Adding Snippet,

```
[Serializable]
        public sealed class BackgroundTaskDescription
        {

            public BackgroundTaskDescription()
            {
                Subject = string.Empty;
                Message = string.Empty;
                dueTime = string.Empty;
                Emails = new List<string>();
            }

            public string Subject { get; set; }
            public string Message { get; set; }
            public string dueTime { get; set; }
            public List<string> Emails { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: winrt does not support [Serializable].

Answer (score 0):

I found solution by changing structure of class as shown below

```
public sealed class BackgroundTaskDescription
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string dueTime { get; set; }
    public string[] Emails { get; set; }
}
```